# Detecting Shift + Return in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I'm using the following code to detect the return key in a text view.  How do you detect if the shift key is being pressed too?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    if(commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
    {
        // return key
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

subclass NSTextView and override flagsChanged with this

```
-(void) flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask && [theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) {

       NSLog(@"pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked!  I just needed if([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask) for the shift key.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {

    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) {
        print("shift!")
    }

    super.flagsChanged(with: event)
}
```